# Calling base class's overloaded method

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods, overloading

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public: void Print(int i) {cout<<i;}
};

class B : public A {
    public: void Print(string s) {cout<<s;}
};

int main() {
    B bInstance;
    bInstance.Print(1);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

meaning it is trying to call B's Print without considering the inherited overload. But, A's Print should be callable by a B instance. In fact, if I change the call to

```
bInstance.A::Print(1);
```

then it compiles without any errors, but I wanted to avoid having to write the class scope operator each time.
Is there a way to tell the compiler I am trying to call the base class's overload of the function?

Comment: Overload resolution is done before searching `A` because it found something in `B`. Use a `using` statement to bring `A`'s in and have it participate in overload resolution.

Comment: If I may humbly suggest that the usefulness of overloading is sometimes somewhat overrated.  Consider using distinct names instead, such as `void printInt( int i );` and `void printString( string s );`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Print()` member function in your subclass *hides* the member function `Print()` of the superclass. Therefore, the compiler will not see `A::Print()` and will try to invoke `B::Print()`, complaining that an `int` could not be converted into a string.

To bring `A::Print()` into the overload set, you can introduce a `using` declaration:

```
class A {
public: 
    void Print(int i) {cout<<i;}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    using A::Print;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    void Print(string s) {cout<<s;}
};
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/N6QE5$1) of your code working after the necessary modifications.

Comment: Added that line, it now gives 'error: void A::Print(int) is inaccessible'.

Comment: @Mic, Put it in the `public:` part of `B`. I'm guessing you added it before your `public: void Print(string s) {cout<<s;}` line, which would make it private.

Comment: I didn't notice the 'public' part of the 'using A::Print' statement, your answer has been clear and accurate, thank you!

Comment: Link broken with the live example. Good example though.